# How can I execute T-SQL code when a record is inserted into a table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, count

I have a table that has N records but this is in constant grow of records, today has 10, tomorrow 11, etc. But not all the time is updated, the information of the table is used to update other tables by a stored procedure, however this procedure should run only when there is new records, is there a way about how to decide to run the procedure based on the count of records?

In simple way, if count of records increases then execute the procedure, if not then don't execute it.

Appreciate the ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DML trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189799.aspx) for new inserted rows. For example, AFTER INSERT DML trigger. It will let you know when there is a new row in a table and you can get the information about this new row. I hope it will be useful for you.